# How should I use the library as librabbitmq-objc?

Tags: objective-c, rabbitmq, amqp

On my server are using RabbitMQ Server and client-side android RabbitMQ Client also used. Now I'm doing for iOS (not Mac) and found this bookshop profmaad made ​​by:

https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc

I copy the project classes and I get an error "file not found Cocoa.h" then replace by "Foundation.h" and it worked. But now I ask the class amqp.h tells me "file not found amqp.h" and does not exist. 
But, It's using it.

And looking I saw that this class was a C, and now is not how to import the class or add amqp.h?

My problem is: How I can to use the library amqp.h or import the class?

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>    <----- Replace Foundation.h (Equivalent)

# import <amqp.h>          <----- ?? When was file? or How import this file?

# import "AMQPConnection.h"
# import "AMQPObject.h"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For using in iOS**

**Delete:**

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
```

**Use:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

**And if file not found using this:**

```
# import <amqp.h>
```

**Use this:**

```
# import "amqp.h"
```

This will almost solve your problem. You may get some error on uint64 fix it as xcode suggests you. And it will work fine.

I am also using  [Objective-C wrapper for librabbitmq-c](https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc) library. I am able to connect, create exchange, create queue, bind queue but i am not able to publish any message using this code:

```
amqp_basic_properties_t props;
    props._flags= AMQP_BASIC_CLASS;
    props.type = amqp_cstring_bytes([@"typeOfMessage" UTF8String]);
    props.priority = 1;
    [exchange publishMessage:@"Hello Friends" usingRoutingKey:@"hello" propertiesMessage:props mandatory:NO immediate:NO error:&error];
```

No error, No exception, i don't know why this is not working !!! I am still looking for the exact solution.

See this, it may help you
[Objective-C RabbitMQ client not publishing messages to queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795180/objective-c-rabbitmq-client-not-publishing-messages-to-queue/24850380#24850380)