# Not able to build rabbitmq-c for iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, xcode, rabbitmq

I am trying to use RabbitMq in an iOS app. As [recommended](https://www.rabbitmq.com/devtools.html), I am using this Objective-C [wrapper](https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc), which stipulates : *There is nothing to build. Just include the source and header files into your Xcode project and link it againt librabbitmq-c.* However, I have been unable to build the app so far. I am using the last stable versions available on GitHub.

1/ I have tried to include all files (both rabbitmq-objc and rabbitmq-c) in my project, and build as usual (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795180/objective-c-rabbitmq-client-not-publishing-messages-to-queue?rq=1)). After replacing a few types (uint8 into u_int8_t) and solving a few imports ("amqp.h" instead of < amqp.h>) as suggested by XCode, I ended up with this error : *Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 254*. I deep cleaned project, erased content of ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData, but no luck.

2/ I have then tried to build rabbitmq-c with cmake via command-line :

```
mkdir build && cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Release
```

And then importing as a dynamic lib in my project. When linking in the project, XCode complains that *building for iOS Simulator, but linking against dylib built for MacOSX file*. I have read a few post on how to address this issue, but I am not sure exactly how to proceed.

3/ I have thus finally used the CMake.app for MacOS, setting the generator to XCode. I have imported the rabbitmq-c.xcodeproj built as a dynamic lib, and set the header path to the correct folder. After setting the Other linker flags to -ObjC -all_load, I still get an error : *no such file or directory: '/Users/Guillaume/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RabbitMQSandbox-bvhczedxhtejhxcwdqmdewzzexjj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/librabbitmq.4.0.0.dylib'*.

I am losing hope. Can somebody point me toward the right direction ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it, here it is for further reference

1/ get the latest [rabbitmq-c](https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c) and [rabbitmq-objc](https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc) libraries.

2/ make sure [Cmake](http://www.cmake.org/download/) is updated (2.6 or better)

3/ install [iOS-cmake](https://code.google.com/p/ios-cmake/)

4/ in rabbitmq-c directory (change OSX_ARCHITECTURES and IOS_PLATFORM flags for simulator or device)

```
mkdir build.ios && cd build.ios
cmake -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/iOS.cmake 
-DIOS_PLATFORM=SIMULATOR (resp. OS) 
-DCMAKE_IOS_DEVELOPER_ROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer     
-DCMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk 
-DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 (resp. i386)
-DBUILD_STATIC_LIBS=True 
-DENABLE_SSL_SUPPORT=False 
-GXcode ..
```

5/ in build.os/librabbitmq, rename directory Debug to Debug-iphonesimulator. Open in XCode the librabbitmq-c.xcodeproj, select target rabbitmq-static, build, and close this project.

6/ import in project that will be using the library librabbitmq.a. In build settings, make sure that `Always Search User Paths` is set to Yes and that `User Header Search Path` contains both paths to rabbitmq-c/librabbitmq and to rabbitmq-c/build.ios/rabbitmq-c.

7/ copy the rabbitmq-objc classes in the project, and set -fno-objc-arc flag for those classes.

8/ Replace occurences of `uint8` by `u_int8_t`, replace occurences of `#import < Cocoa/Cocoa.h>` by `#import < Foundation/Foundation.h>`, replace occurences of `#import < amqp.h>` and `#import < amqp_framing.h>` by `#import "amqp.h"` and `#import "amqp_framing.h"`.

9/ In AMQPConsumer.m, add missing parameter AMQP_EMPTY_TABLE in function amqp_basic_consume, and in AMQPExchange.m, add missing

```
#define AMQP_EXCHANGE_TYPE_DIRECT @"direct" 
#define AMQP_EXCHANGE_TYPE_FANOUT @"fanout"
#define AMQP_EXCHANGE_TYPE_TOPIC @"topic"
```

10/ Build project.