# Compiling rabbitmq-c with ios-cmake

Tags: ios, xcode, rabbitmq-c

I have been trying to compile rabbitmq-c as per hte instructions from R_R ([Not able to build rabbitmq-c for iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242125/not-able-to-build-rabbitmq-c-for-ios-application)) but I get the following error:

> CMake Error at /Users/karela/appDir/ios-cmake/toolchain/iOS.cmake:101 (message): No iOS SDK's found in default seach path /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer. Manually set CMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT or install the iOS SDK.

I have searched all I could but cannot figure out what's wrong. Probably something with ios-cmake toolchain but not sure why and how to fix it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I'm using ios-cmake too, even if I didn't success yet, I can give you the solution of your problem.

When you use cmake, you should add this :

```
-DCMAKE_IOS_SDK_ROOT=/path/to/Platform/Developer/SDK
```

For exemple, this is my path :

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk
```