# iOS: Unable to establish RabbitMQ connection from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, rabbitmq, ios9

I am trying to connect RabbitMQ from Swift. I have followed [this](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/) library. Created pod setup and entered into workspace. Checked and verified. Successfully running.

**viewDidLoad**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
connRabbMQ = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://test:test@192.***.**.17:15672", delegate: RMQConnectionDelegateLogger())
connRabbMQ.start()
}
```

**Output Logs:**

```
2016-07-08 10:47:47.943 Demo_Rabb[784:38644] Received connection:
<RMQConnection: 0x7fe458c3a420> failedToConnectWithError: Error
 Domain=com.rabbitmq.rabbitmq-objc-client Code=1 "Handshake timed out." 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Handshake timed out.
}
```

I dont know what is happening. Kindly guide me how to connect with backend.

Comment: First you must check if your request reaches your backend. Handshake timed out might be happening because you are not sending all the required info to the server. Server might be generating some logs if there is any error.

Comment: That only I dnt know,, How To chk? @Nil

Comment: That you need to check with your server guy. He must know the ip, port, uri etc etc..

Comment: @Nil  I having all those details. But, dont know why this error happening.

Comment: May be check your firewall? I had a case where my firewall was blocking a particular port number. So I was not able to send a handshake message from that particular port. Or that port might be already occupied.

Comment: No firewall blocked. Can u pls just dwnload, and import that pod file in ur proj and run it?  kindly help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem ,I found out I've used incorrect port number, Port 15672 is for web access,you must use Port 5672 for swift client or another client application to access direct to rabbtiMQ server

Comment: I am having this error: "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}