# Cloud AMPQ integration with iOS APP

Tags: ios, swift, rabbitmq

I am working on to integrate cloud AMPQ to my iOS app. With RabbitMQ client, unable to make successful communication with the server.

I have checked below stack overflow link to make a communication with the server: 
[stack overflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795180/objective-c-rabbitmq-client-not-publishing-messages-to-queue?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

The sample source shared in above link broken. Please suggest me possible solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: you get any console report for break connection

Comment: Actually, If I add RabbitMq-C library to main source that will throw lot of errors like "htonll - not found", some default error key not found(XMLTO_EXECUTABLE). If you have setup(code) to make communication with subscribe and publish services. Share me

Comment: can you add your errors

Comment: I tried 2 methods,
     In first method while make communication with RabbitMQclient ( https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client ), I get two errors randomly
     1. borken pipe
     2. handshake timeout
     In second method with RabbitMq-C library( https://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c ) and librabbitmq-objc( https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc ), I got some errors like "htonll - not found" and some default error key not found(XMLTO_EXECUTABLE) in integrating libraries into main source.

Comment: can you add your console error

Comment: Why not use https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client instead ? The example works perfectly with a RabbitMQ server (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/#basic-usage-example)

Comment: @Nathan, I am using the remote AMPQ URI, Not localhost. with this case, I need to give username, password and unique client id(used for unique device identification) configured in server. From RabbitMQ, How can i pass credentials to make communication?. Please add your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried searching their repo ? Auth using user/password: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client/issues/123

Comment: @Nathan,  I also used above library with crdentials (uesrname/password). But that throws an error "socket connection closed by remote peer"

Comment: @Nathan, I tried all posibilities. Each one one has some curdles. I am struck in half way. I thing, i need to configure client id, while making connection request.  I don't know how to set client id to make an connection with servet. Help me. Thankyou

Comment: The client ID along with the credentials can be sent using the provided connection string. Heroku for example already provides a ready to use connection string that includes the user/password/clientId/system key/etc https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-query-parameters.html

Comment: Okay. I will check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the official client library: https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client (Swift + ObjC compatible)

Basic Usage (extract from repo):

1. Instantiate an RMQConnection:

   ```
   let delegate = RMQConnectionDelegateLogger() // implement RMQConnectionDelegate yourself to react to errors
   let conn = RMQConnection(uri: "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672", delegate: delegate)
   ```
2. Connect:

   ```
   conn.start()
   ```
3. Create a channel:

   ```
   let ch = conn.createChannel()
   ```
4. Use the channel:

   ```
   let q = ch.queue("myqueue")
   q.subscribe({ m in
       print("Received: \(String(data: m.body, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8))")
   })
   q.publish("foo".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8))
   ```
5. Close the connection when done:

   ```
   conn.close()
   ```

Depending on the provider, you'll need to construct the connection URI manually. Heroku for example already presents it in it's dashboard. Here's the documentation on the supported parameters: https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-spec.html and https://www.rabbitmq.com/uri-query-parameters.html

Example URI on Heroku:

```
amqp://xxxxxxx:yyy-zzz@aaaaaa.bigwig.lshift.net:10674/bbbbbbb
```

Format:

```
amqp_URI = "amqp://" [ username [ ":" password ] "@" ] host [ ":" port ] [ "/" vhost ] [ "?" query ]
```

Comment: not working getting error "Socket closed by remote peer"