# communication between iOS device and unity application in windows via socket connection(no url)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Please suggest me how can we communicate between iOS device and windows unity application.
I am trying to use RabbitMQ library. I am new to socket connections. 
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-objc-client

I have followed this link: [Objective-C RabbitMQ client not publishing messages to queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24795180/objective-c-rabbitmq-client-not-publishing-messages-to-queue)

But while importing the library and header files i am having lots of issues.

Please suggest me the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just use raw socket from C# API. That should work

Comment: Thanks for the response. Any samples or guiding links will be helpful because i am new to sockets.

Comment: Just Google "C# socket server and client". It should work in Unity. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36526332/unity3d-c-sharp-plugin-to-act-as-a-socket-server/36526634?s=1|54.9953#36526634) is an example for Unity